# Misleading post preview. Links visible in preview are not links when posted question

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, markdown-preview

Check this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14191857/719457).

Some links in brackets () are not highlighted as hyperlinks. However when you edit post, in preview, all links looks correct.

It seems that brackets around hyperlinks prevent treating http link as proper hyperlink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only post more than two hyperlinks if you have more than 10 reputation points. Probably the user posted his answer when he didn't yet have 10 rep points. I think that when he would edit his answer now, *all* hyperlinks are highlighted.

More info about this privilege: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user

Comment: You are right. I edited it to make links clickable and it worked.

Comment: @omikron Keep in mind that your edits go through the suggested edit queue. Not always the good intent of an edit is understood. Your edit was rejected by the reviewers. I'm now the latest editor on that post and that was not to kick you out or overrule your actions.

Comment: @rene I see some kind of edit war on mentioned SO answer now. ;) Your edit also was replaced. PS. I saw my edit was rejected by you but it's OK, your was better.

Comment: OGHaza has edited and that looks fine as he probably is more knowledgeable on this linux stuff then myself. I was unsure if all that stuff were commands, configsettings or GUI options